# inconsistent loading of image overlays using div with background-image

Tags: jquery, image, load, overlay, background-image

I'm using jQuery to add some image overlays on top of product images, but I'm having trouble getting the overlays to show up consistently.

css in the body of the page define the overlay background-image paths:

```
<body>
.... //products grid
    <div class="producttile" data-overlay-pid="abc"> ...</div> 
     //end products grid
  <style>
    .top_seller { background-image: url('http://mysite.com/overlays/top_seller.png');}
    .clearance { background-image: url('http://mysite.com/overlays/clearance.png');}
  </style>
</body>
```

I'm using full paths, so I don't have any relative path issues.

Once the page loads, I make an ajax call to a web-service to return JSON info re: which product should get which overlays.  The json response contains a callback name and params for the callback:

```
[{"params":{"pid":"abc","overlay":"top_seller"},"callback":"setOverlay"},{"params":{"pid":"xyz","overlay":"clearance"},"callback":"setOverlay"}]
```

The ajax call finishes and invokes the callback function which creates a an empty div, assigns it the overlay class and prepends it to the product div.

```
setOverlay : function(params) {
  var pid = params['pid'];
  var el = jQuery(selector + "[data-overlay-pid='"+params['pid']+"']");
    //inject an overlay on this element
    //add div with class of size
    el.css('position','relative');
    var new_overlay = jQuery('<div>');
    new_overlay.attr('class',params['overlay']);
    new_overlay.prependTo(el);
}
```

I tested this with 2 different overlays and this process appears to be working fine in chrome.  But in firefox, one of the overlays loads but not the other overlay.  When I look at the net console the 2nd overlay background image is never loaded.  This inconsistency across browsers feels like a race condition to me where the background image isn't fully loaded to be available, but I couldn't find any information for fixing it.

I'm already using document.ready before calling my ajax script.  How do I fix it?

UPDATE: all the code/css is simplified to be easier to read.

UPDATE: in firebug, when I inspect the overlay div, the class does not contain the background-image property at all.  in chrome when I inspect the overlay did, the class has the background-image url but there is a line through it and an exclamation saying invalid property value.

Comment: I see your json response contains a class called `top_seller` yet there is no `top_seller` class in the css. Could that be that an error in the code, or have you just omitted some of the css?

Comment: I have just omitted some of the original code.  I was trying to simplify it to be easier to read.